# ELI5: How do I import keys from blockchain.info backup into MultiBit 0.5.18

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key, multibit, import

So, blockchain.info is holding my account hostage. My phone with my 2FA was lost (and remotely wiped) and they refuse to remove the 2FA on my account to get access. I have a recent backup of my keys available but the file does not appear in the file browser (wallet.aes.json) when I select import keys. Everything I've found on the internet says to change the file filter, but there isn't a way to do that in version 0.5.18 that I can plainly see. Can someone please drop some instructions here, step-by-step so I can accomplish a recovery of my coin without the help of the ridiculous folks at blockchain.info?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They aren't holding it hostage, they're following strict rules for **your** security. They cannot tell for sure that the person emailing them is you and not someone trying to bypass the 2FA (which is designed for this very purpose) and steal your coins.

Answer (score 1):

Support for importing blockchain.info wallets was removed in MultiBit 0.5.18. MultiBit still hosts their old releases, however, so you could simply download [0.5.17](https://multibit.org/releases/multibit-0.5.17/), import the blockchain.info wallet, and then upgrade to 0.5.18.

You could also [import the backup](https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet) into a new blockchain.info account. Once it's there, you could send it to a MultiBit address or make [another backup](https://blockchain.info/wallet/backups) in an easier-to-read format (e.g. unencrypted export). You could then [follow the instructions here](https://multibit.org/help_importASingleKey.html) to import those private keys into MultiBit 0.5.18.